# Do I need to patch holes punched thru paper/foil wall insulation?

Tags: insulation

I have a closet where my internet router and some other hardware reside. I intend to route ethernet cables thru the closet to the exterior of the house. The closet has a wall along the outside of the house. I cut a hole in the wall for a 1 gang low voltage 4-port ethernet wall plate. Behind the wall was very thin paper/foil. I cut that as well. Do I need to stuff any kind of insulation around the radius of the hole to ensure I don't have any moisture or heat problems? It'd be great if I could just pop the wall plate on and on the outside, a water proof electrical box. I don't want to significantly compromise insulation against heat, moisture, cold. I live in Florida.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to patch that stuff. Just get any insulation back to uniform thickness.

You should seal the outside hole around any wires, though. Insects are the primary reason. I use duct seal putty for that kind of thing as long as the hole isn't hugely oversized. If you have some exterior grade caulk laying around, then that will work.